# why is this print linked list function not working?

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a function as following

```
void printLinkedList(struct node *head) {

    printf("%d-->", head->data);

    while(head->ptr != NULL) {
        head = head->ptr;
        printf("%d-->", head->data);
    }
    printf("NULL\n");
}
```

I would like to print the content of a linked list constructed in the following way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    head->data = i+1;
    head->ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head = head->ptr;
}
```

So ideally this should give me something like:

```
1-->2-->3-->4-->...-->10-->NULL
```

If everything is correct, however, valgrind is giving me memory errors. Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: In linked list head node(first node) have to be stored so that list can be parsed. In your code your variable named head is modified for each addition and it points to last node. Also you are not assigning NULL to last node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this.

```
struct node *temp, *head= NULL, *last = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp->data = i+1;
        temp->ptr = NULL;
        if (head == NULL)
          head = temp;
        if (last != NULL)
          last->ptr = temp;
        last = temp;
    }
printLinkedList(head);
```

Comment: hmm not sure why but your code gives me a seg fault. I changed my code  given your comment and it works now!:) Thank you!

Comment: its because temp is not declared for the first loop inside for loop

Comment: Well done — you fixed the memory leak just before I got to comment on it.  This code runs cleanly under `valgrind` (when I add a call `free_list(head);` after the `printLinkedList()` call, where `free_list()` is defined as: `void free_list(struct node *head) { while (head != 0) { struct node *next = head->ptr; free(head); head = next; } }`).

Comment: Thank you Toms and Jonathan!
Another somewhat unrelated question is: had I done this in java, how what should the structure of a Node be? `class Node {int data; Node next;}` does something like that make sense as a linked list in Java? Or that's is in essence not a linked list since there is no pointer in Java?

Answer (score 1):

I revised Toms's answer a little:

```
struct node *head = NULL, **temp = &head;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    (*temp)->data = i+1;
    (*temp)->ptr = NULL;
    temp = &(*temp)->ptr;
}
printLinkedList(head);
```

The orignal code produces a seg fault because temp is not malloced properly.

Comment: where is the linking??temp->ptr has to NULL

Comment: I move `temp = temp->ptr` to the end of the loop, and it will be alloced in the next run.

Comment: in the next run in first statement that temp is overwritten.

Comment: I'd like to vote on this, but it does not work.  If you look at the last line before the end of the loop, it assigns `temp = temp->ptr;`, but the first operation on the next iteration is `temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));`, which overwrites the previous assignment.  As a result, the final list that's printed is `1-->NULL`, and when I add a call to `free_list()` after printing, `valgrind` reports 144 bytes leaked in 9 blocks. The `free_list()` function is implemented as: `void free_list(struct node *head) { while (head != 0) { struct node *next = head->ptr; free(head); head = next; } }`.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler @Toms You're right. I declare `temp` as a pointer to pointer now. It should work.

Comment: Hmm...GCC sayeth: `ll.c:22:11: warning: ‘temp’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks. Actually this warning inspires me to make the code shorter.

Comment: OK - that one I can give a thumbs up to; `valgrind` says fine, and the output is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you call print function without constructing the Linked list, it will show error, so change the print function as follows:

```
void printLinkedList(struct node *head) 
{
    while(head != NULL) 
    {
        printf("%d-->", head->data);
        head = head->ptr;
    }
    printf("NULL\n");
 }
```

Comment: It is right only since head is itself a pointer to the Linked list, so we can check that head is null

Answer (score 0):

here is the revised code - your construction was faulty.

```
typedef struct _node {
    int data;
    struct _node *ptr;
} NODE, *PNODE;

PNODE head;

int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{

    head = (PNODE) malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    PNODE node = head;

    int i = 0;
    node->data = ++i;
    node->ptr = NULL;

    for ( ;i < 10; ) {
        PNODE tmp = (PNODE) malloc(sizeof(NODE));
        tmp->data = ++i;
        tmp->ptr = NULL;

        node->ptr = tmp;
        node =tmp;
    }

    printLinkedList(head);

    freeLinkedList(head);

    return 0;

}
```